# std::list::erase(iter) exception handling c++

Tags: c++, list, exception, iterator

I try to get an iterator from a function and then erase an element from a list.

1. Is there any way to catch that exception?
2. Is there any way to know if the iterator is valid?

When I run the program with invalid iterator it throws the following exception:

```
 Exception thrown: read access violation.
 _Right.**_Myproxy** was 0xCCCCCCCC. occurred
```

My func is:

```
list<AccountStruct>::const_iterator SearchAccount(list<AccountStruct>& Acc,string p)
{

    for (list<AccountStruct>::const_iterator j = Acc.begin(); j !=Acc.end(); ++j)
    {
        if ((*j).phone == p) return j;
    }

}

void RemoveAccount(list<AccountStruct>& Acc)
{
    string Phone;
    cout << "Enter Phone Number ->" << endl;
    cin >> Phone;
    //cout << "Searching..." << endl;
    list<AccountStruct>::const_iterator iter = SearchAccount(Acc,Phone);
    try
    {
        Acc.erase(iter);
    }
    catch()// <- What to put inside??
    {
        cout << "No Phone Number;" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your time would be better spent figuring out what's causing the access violation. Is `SearchAccount` returning an iterator to a function local `list`?

Comment: It's not a C++ exception, as such, you can't catch it. You have undefined behavior on this line only if `SearchAccount` returns an iterator of another list.

Comment: I've added the another function to the question

Comment: Your `SearchAccount` function has undefined behavior.  It doesn't return anything if the object is not found.

Comment: @NathanOliver How can I return a valid iterator which will not cause erase inside a list if nothing found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can fix this with a couple changes.  First, `SearchAccount` doesn't return anything if the function does not find an object.  This is undefined behavior, as you must return something when you say you will.  We can fix this by returning `end()` if the item is not found like `find` does.  That gives you

```
list<AccountStruct>::const_iterator SearchAccount(list<AccountStruct>& Acc,string p)
{
    for (list<AccountStruct>::const_iterator j = Acc.begin(); j !=Acc.end(); ++j)
    {
        if ((*j).phone == p) return j;
    }
    return Acc.end(); // item not found
}
```

Now that `SearchAccount` functions properly we can then check to see if `end()` is returned instead of using the exception mechanism.  That look like

```
void RemoveAccount(list<AccountStruct>& Acc)
{
    string Phone;
    cout << "Enter Phone Number ->" << endl;
    cin >> Phone;
    //cout << "Searching..." << endl;
    list<AccountStruct>::const_iterator iter = SearchAccount(Acc,Phone);
    if (iter != Acc.end())
    {
        Acc.erase(iter);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No Phone Number;" << endl;
    }
}
```

And now you don't have the overhead of the exception mechanism and the "right thing" happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`::std::remove_if` algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

```
Acc.erase
(
    ::std::remove_if
    (
        Acc.begin()
    ,   Acc.end()
    ,   [&Phone](AccountStruct const & acc)
        {
            return(acc.phone == Phone);
        }
    )
,   Acc.end()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::list::erase` does not throw any exception.

The `try` block is not necessary. However an invalid iterator will cause undefined behavior.

You could return `Acc.end()` at after the `for` loop in `SearchAccount` and check the returned value against `Acc.end` instead of using `try`.